# Bpython error on cmd line : no module named 'termios'

Tags: python, command-line, bpython

Trying to follow this video on windows 10:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZdsQbTFpAQ] at 13min54s the coder instructs to run **bpython**.

I get this log error:

**(venv) (base) PS C:\Users\Desktop\mazeProject> bpython**
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code   File "C:\Users\Desktop\venv\Scripts\bpython.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>   File "C:\Users\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages\bpython\curtsies.py", line 10, in <module>     import curtsies   File "C:\Users\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages\curtsies\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>     from .window import FullscreenWindow, CursorAwareWindow   File "C:\Users\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages\curtsies\window.py", line 30, in <module>     from .termhelpers import Cbreak   File "C:\Users\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages\curtsies\termhelpers.py", line 1, in <module>     import tty   File "C:\Users\Desktop\anaconda3\Lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>     from termios import * **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'**`

Did anybody run into this error before?
Thanks in advance,

Trying to run BPYTHON

Expected to be able to import project file as IMPORT <PROJECT_NAME> after bpython command

Comment: I'm not sure `termios` is available on Windows.

Comment: `bpython` doesn't seem to officially support Windows.  You might have better luck running `bpython-curses` instead of the regular `bpython` - but I suspect that this would change the user experience enough that you wouldn't be able to follow that Youtube video.

Comment: It appears bpython is only supported on Linux, indeed. Any walk around does come to your minds? Thanks, guys.